# Rails ActionMailer nested within modules

Tags: nested, actionmailer, ruby-on-rails-5.1

Is it possible to have a rails mailer inside of a module and still have it work fine, so for example:

```
module Some
  module Deeply
    module Nested
      class Mailer < ApplicationMailer
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Also do I need to place in within a folder structure like:

```
app/mailers/some/deeply/nested/mailer.rb
```

or is

```
app/mailers/mailer.rb
```

perfectly fine?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is you can, but if you nest the mailer then you need to place the file in a nested folder structure that matches the module nesting.